# How to set breakpoint with gdb on function from stripped shared library?

Tags: gdb, shared-libraries, reverse, decompiling, disassembly

I've got an executable file and **stripped** `lib.so` file that is used by executable.
I have decompiled `lib.so` file and defined the function `fun` I want to set breakpoint and its internal address.

Is it possible to set breakpoint on function `fun` using gdb?
How to define the address of `fun` at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to set breakpoint on function `fun` using gdb?

Yes: GDB can set a breakpoint on arbitrary address:

```
(gdb) break *0x12345678
```

> How to define the address of fun at runtime?

Since GDB by default disables ASLR, the address of `fun` will not change from run to run (assuming you run the program under GDB from the start).

Therefore, you only need to find the address of `fun` once.

Let's assume that your `lib.so` is linked at `0` (most non-prelinked shared libraries are).

Further let's assume that you are on Linux.

Then `info proc map` will tell you where the `lib.so` is loaded (you want the first start address belonging to it). Add that start address to the value of `fun` you found by disassembling, and set a breakpoint there.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend! You saved my day:)